# Is there any way to do 128-bit shifts on gcc <4.4?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-shift, 128-bit

`gcc` 4.4 seems to be the first version when they added `int128_t`. I need to use bit shifting and I have run out of room for some bit fields.

**Edit**: It might be because I'm on a 32-bit computer, there's no way to have it for a 32-bit computer (Intel Atom), is there? I wouldn't care if it generated tricky slow machine code if I would work as expected with bit shifting.

Comment: This is a special case of [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088282) which does cover the fact that GCC4.1 and later have `__uint128_t`, but only on 64-bit targets.  That question *doesn't* attempt to provide workarounds, other than C23 `_BitInt(128)` supported by clang even on 32-bit machines, so maybe not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure that `__int128_t` is available on earlier versions of gcc. Just checked on 4.2.1 and FreeBSD and `sizeof(__int128_t)` gives 16.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the earlier gcc 4.1.2 (e.g. as in RHEL 5)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey It [does work with gcc 4.1.2](https://godbolt.org/z/ybSSRn)

Comment: unfortunately this won't work for the OP since he's using a 32-bit OS. GCC only supports types twice as wide as the register size, thus `__int128_t` won't be available if compiled with `-m32`

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a library. This would have the advantage that it is portable (regarding platform and compiler) and you could easily switch to even bigger datatype. One I could recommend is gmp (even if its intention is not to handle bitwidth x, but variable as big as you want).

Answer (score 2):

Bit shifting is very easy in any arbitrary number of bits. Just remember to shift the overflowed bits to the next limb. That's all

```
typedef struct {
   int64_t high;
   uint64_t low;
} int128_t;


int128_t shift_left(int128_t v, unsigned shiftcount)
{
   int128_t result;
   result.high = (v.high << shiftcount) | (v.low >> (64 - shiftcount));
   result.low  =  v.low  << shiftcount;
   return result;
}
```

Similar for shift right

```
int128_t shift_right(int128_t v, unsigned shiftcount)
{
   int128_t result;
   result.low  = (v.low  >> shiftcount) | (v.high << (64 - shiftcount));
   result.high =  v.high >> shiftcount;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two 64-bit ints, but then you need to keep track of the bits moving between.