# Fast implementation of a large integer counter (in C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm

My goal is as the following,

Generate successive values, such that each new one was never generated before, until all possible values are generated. At this point, the counter start the same sequence again. The main point here is that, *all* possible values are generated *without repetition* (until the period is exhausted). It does not matter if the sequence is simple 0, 1, 2, 3,..., or in other order.

For example, if the range can be represented simply by an `unsigned`, then

```
void increment (unsigned &n) {++n;}
```

is enough. However, the integer range is larger than 64-bits. For example, in one place, I need to generated 256-bits sequence. A simple implementation is like the following, just to illustrate what I am trying to do,

```
typedef std::array<uint64_t, 4> ctr_type;
static constexpr uint64_t max = ~((uint64_t) 0);
void increment (ctr_type &ctr)
{
    if (ctr[0] < max) {++ctr[0]; return;}
    if (ctr[1] < max) {++ctr[1]; return;}
    if (ctr[2] < max) {++ctr[2]; return;}
    if (ctr[3] < max) {++ctr[3]; return;}
    ctr[0] = ctr[1] = ctr[2] = ctr[3] = 0;
}
```

So if `ctr` start with all zeros, then first `ctr[0]` is increased one by one until it reach `max`, and then `ctr[1]`, and so on. If all 256-bits are set, then we reset it to all zero, and start again.

The problem is that, such implementation is surprisingly slow. My current improved version is sort of equivalent to the following,

```
void increment (ctr_type &ctr)
{
    std::size_t k = (!(~ctr[0])) + (!(~ctr[1])) + (!(~ctr[2])) + (!(~ctr[3]))
    if (k < 4)
        ++ctr[k];
    else
        memset(ctr.data(), 0, 32);

}
```

If the counter is only manipulated with the above `increment` function, and always start with zero, then `ctr[k] == 0` if `ctr[k - 1] == 0`. And thus the value `k` will be the index of the first element that is less than the maximum.

I expected the first to be faster, since branch mis-prediction shall happen only once in every 2^64 iterations. The second, though mis-predication only happen every 2^256 iterations, it shall not make a difference. And apart from the branching, it needs four bitwise negation, four boolean negation, and three addition. Which might cost much more than the first.

However, both `clang`, `gcc`, or intel `icpc` generate binaries that the second was much faster.

My main question is that does anyone know if there any faster way to implement such a counter? It does not matter if the counter start by increasing the first integers or if it is implemented as an array of integers at all, as long as the algorithm generate all 2^256 combinations of 256-bits.

What makes things more complicated, I also need non uniform increment. For example, each time the counter is incremented by `K` where `K > 1`, but almost always remain a constant. My current implementation is similar to the above.

To provide some more context, one place I am using the counters is using them as input to AES-NI aesenc instructions. So distinct 128-bits integer (loaded into `__m128i`), after going through 10 (or 12 or 14, depending on the key size) rounds of the instructions, a distinct `128-bits` integer is generated. If I generate one `__m128i` integer at once, then the cost of `increment` matters little. However, since aesenc has quite a bit latency, I generate integers by blocks. For example, I might have 4 blocks, `ctr_type block[4]`, initialized equivalent to the following,

```
block[0]; // initialized to zero
block[1] = block[0]; increment(block[1]);
block[2] = block[1]; increment(block[2]);
block[3] = block[2]; increment(block[3]);
```

And each time I need new output, I `increment` each `block[i]` by 4, and generate 4 `__m128i` output at once. By interleaving instructions, overall I was able to increase the throughput, and reduce the cycles per bytes of output (cpB) from 6 to 0.9 when using 2 64-bits integers as the counter and 8 blocks. However, if instead, use 4 32-bits integers as counter, the throughput, measured as bytes per sec is reduced to half. I know for a fact that on x86-64, 64-bits integers could be faster than 32-bits in some situations. But I did not expect such simple increment operation makes such a big difference. I have carefully benchmarked the application, and the `increment` is indeed the one slow down the program. Since the loading into `__m128i` and store the `__m128i` output into usable 32-bits or 64-bits integers are done through aligned pointers, the only difference between the 32-bits and 64-bits version is how the counter is incremented. I expected that the AES-NI expected, after loading the integers into `__m128i`, shall dominate the performance. But when using 4 or 8 blocks, it was clearly not the case.

So to summary, my main question is that, if anyone know a way to improve the above counter implementation.

Comment: How quickly do you expect a 64 bit counter to overflow?  By my math, it would take ~300 years if you could update it at 2GHz.  A 256 bit counter is mind bogglingly huge.

Comment: Are you attempting a brute force attack on AES256???

Comment: why did someone downvote this question.

Comment: Is it really 2^256 combinations you want, or 2^66, which is what you have written? Anyway, during anybodys lifetime, an early exit dominates the performance.

Comment: The speed of light isn't fast enough to let you brute force AES-256. `E=MC^2` just isn't enough energy even when you throw in the entire mass-energy of the observable universe. (dark matter included)

Answer (score 4):

It's not only slow, but impossible. The total energy of universe is insufficient for 2^256 bit changes. And that would require gray counter.

Next thing before optimization is to fix the original implementation

```
void increment (ctr_type &ctr)
{
    if (++ctr[0] != 0) return;
    if (++ctr[1] != 0) return;
    if (++ctr[2] != 0) return;
    ++ctr[3];
}
```

If each `ctr[i]` was not allowed to overflow to zero, the period would be just 4*(2^32), as in `0-9`, `19,29,39,49,...99`, `199,299,...` and `1999,2999,3999,..., 9999`.

As a reply to the comment -- it takes 2^64 iterations to have the first overflow. Being generous, upto 2^32 iterations could take place in a second, meaning that the program should run 2^32 seconds to have the first carry out. That's about 136 years.

**EDIT**

If the original implementation with 2^66 states is really what is wanted, then I'd suggest to change the interface and the functionality to something like:

```
  (*counter) += 1;
  while (*counter == 0)
  {
     counter++;  // Move to next word
     if (counter > tail_of_array) {
        counter = head_of_array;
        memset(counter,0, 16);
        break;
     }
  }
```

The point being, that the overflow is still very infrequent. Almost always there's just one word to be incremented.

Comment: Traditionally one uses an add-with-carry instruction to efficiently implement multi-precision add, but this is sadly not available in C or C++ without inline asm.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GCC or compilers with [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) like Clang or ICC

```
unsigned __int128 H = 0, L = 0;
L++;
if (L == 0) H++;
```

On systems where `__int128` isn't available

```
std::array<uint64_t, 4> c[4]{};
c[0]++;
if (c[0] == 0)
{
    c[1]++;
    if (c[1] == 0)
    {
        c[2]++;
        if (c[2] == 0)
        {
            c[3]++;
        }
    }
}
```

In inline assembly it's much easier to do this using the carry flag. Unfortunately most high level languages don't have means to access it directly. Some compilers do have intrinsics for adding with carry like [`__builtin_uaddll_overflow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) in GCC and [`__builtin_addcll`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

Anyway this is rather wasting time since the total number of particles in the universe is only about 10<sup>80</sup> and you cannot even count up the 64-bit counter in your life

Comment: Thanks for highlighting 128-bit implementation in GCC, available since ... 2003 (more than 10 years ago). GCC generates nearly-optimal branch-free code from  H += (++L == 0)

Comment: @Pierre officially it was announced in [GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html) which was released in 2009, but 128-bit int support was already available from [GCC 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5576217/995714#comment90833163_5576526) around 2006-2007 although I don't know the first version that introduced this feature

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your counter versions increment correctly. Instead of counting up to `UINT256_MAX`, you are actually just counting up to `UINT64_MAX` 4 times and then starting back at 0 again. This is apparent from the fact that you do not bother to clear any of the indices that has reached the max value until all of them have reached the max value. If you are measuring performance based on how often the counter reaches all bits 0, then this is why. Thus your algorithms do not generate all combinations of 256 bits, which is a stated requirement.

Comment: No, it won't. The first carry out may not happen for hundreds of years.

Answer (score 0):

You mention **"Generate successive values, such that each new one was never generated before"**

To generate a set of such values, look at [linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

- the sequence x = (x*1 + 1) % (power_of_2), you thought about it, this are simply sequential numbers.
- the sequence x = (x*13 + 137) % (power of 2) , this generates unique numbers with a predictable period (power_of_2 - 1) and the unique numbers look more "random", kind of pseudo-random. You need to resort to arbitrary precision arithmetic to get it working, and also all the trickeries of multiplications by constants. This will get you a nice way to start.

You also complain that your simple code is **"slow"**

At 4.2 GHz frequency, running 4 intructions per cycle and using AVX512 vectorizations, on a 64-core computer with a multithreaded version of your program doing nothing else than increments, you get only 64x8x4*2<sup>32</sup>=8796093022208 increments per second, that is 2<sup>64</sup> increments reached in 25 days. This post is old, you might have reached 841632698362998292480 by now, running such a program on such a machine, and you will gloriously reach 1683265396725996584960 in 2 years time.

You also require **"until all possible values are generated"**.

You can only generate a finite number of values, depending how much you are willing to pay for the energy to power your computers. As mentioned in the other responses, with 128 or 256-bit numbers, even being the richest man in the world, you will never wrap around before the first of these conditions occurs:

- getting out of money
- end of humankind (nobody will get the outcome of your software)
- burning the energy from the last particles of the universe

Comment: suppose you can reach 2^64 in 1 month, then you'll need 2^192 months to reach 2^256 which is ~5.23e56 years

Answer (score 0):

Multi-word addition can easily be accomplished in *portable* fashion by using three macros that mimic three types of addition instructions found on many processors:

`ADDcc` adds two words, and sets the carry if their was unsigned overflow
`ADDC` adds two words plus carry (from a previous addition)
`ADDCcc` adds two words plus carry, and sets the carry if their was unsigned overflow

A multi-word addition with two words uses `ADDcc` of the least significant words followed by `ADCC` of the most significant words. A multi-word addition with more than two words forms sequence `ADDcc`, `ADDCcc`, ..., `ADDC`. The MIPS architecture is a processor architecture without conditions code and therefore without carry flag. The macro implementations shown below basically follow the techniques used on MIPS processors for multi-word additions.

The ISO-C99 code below shows the operation of a 32-bit counter and a 64-bit counter based on 16-bit "words". I chose arrays as the underlying data structure, but one might also use `struct`, for example. Use of a `struct` will be significantly faster if each operand only comprises a few words, as the overhead of array indexing is eliminated. One would want to use the widest available integer type for each "word" for best performance. In the example from the question that would likely be a 256-bit counter comprising four `uint64_t` components.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ADDCcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) \
  (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), cy=t0<cy, t0=t0+t1, t1=t0<t1, cy=cy+t1, t0=t0)

#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) \
  (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)

#define ADDC(a,b,cy,t0,t1) \
  (t0=(b)+cy, t1=(a), t0+t1)

typedef uint16_t T;

/* increment a multi-word counter comprising n words */
void inc_array (T *counter, const T *increment, int n)
{
    T cy, t0, t1;
    counter [0] = ADDcc (counter [0], increment [0], cy, t0, t1);
    for (int i = 1; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        counter [i] = ADDCcc (counter [i], increment [i], cy, t0, t1);
    }
    counter [n-1] = ADDC (counter [n-1], increment [n-1], cy, t0, t1);
}

#define INCREMENT (10)
#define UINT32_ARRAY_LEN (2)
#define UINT64_ARRAY_LEN (4)

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t count32 = 0, incr32 = INCREMENT;
    T count_arr2 [UINT32_ARRAY_LEN] = {0};
    T incr_arr2  [UINT32_ARRAY_LEN] = {INCREMENT};
    do {
        count32 = count32 + incr32;
        inc_array (count_arr2, incr_arr2, UINT32_ARRAY_LEN);
    } while (count32 < (0U - INCREMENT - 1));
    printf ("count32 = %08x  arr_count = %08x\n", 
            count32, (((uint32_t)count_arr2 [1] << 16) +
                      ((uint32_t)count_arr2 [0] <<  0)));

    uint64_t count64 = 0, incr64 = INCREMENT;
    T count_arr4 [UINT64_ARRAY_LEN] = {0};
    T incr_arr4  [UINT64_ARRAY_LEN] = {INCREMENT};
    do {
        count64 = count64 + incr64;
        inc_array (count_arr4, incr_arr4, UINT64_ARRAY_LEN);
    } while (count64 < 0xa987654321ULL);
    printf ("count64 = %016llx  arr_count = %016llx\n", 
            count64, (((uint64_t)count_arr4 [3] << 48) + 
                      ((uint64_t)count_arr4 [2] << 32) +
                      ((uint64_t)count_arr4 [1] << 16) +
                      ((uint64_t)count_arr4 [0] <<  0)));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled with full optimization, the 32-bit example executes in about a second, while the 64-bit example runs for about a minute on a modern PC. The output of the program should look like so:

```
count32 = fffffffa  arr_count = fffffffa
count64 = 000000a987654326  arr_count = 000000a987654326
```

Non-portable code that is based on inline assembly or proprietary extensions for wide integer types may execute about two to three times as fast as the portable solution presented here.