# Is there a way to use __int128_t with the Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, g++, int128

Is there a way to use __int128_t with the Android NDK?

I tried to use GNU toolchain 4.9 but I get the following error no matter how I try:
`error: '__int128_t' was not declared in this scope`

`-std=gnu++11` is enabled of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use __int128_t with the Android NDK?

I don't believe so. `__int128_t` is emulated, and its only available on 64-bit platforms. Its not available on Android at the moment, which is a 32-bit platform. See [Is __int128_t arithmetic emulated by GCC, even with SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566437/is-int128-t-arithmetic-emulated-by-gcc-even-with-sse).

You can check for availability of `__int128_t` by detecting the presence of the macro `__SIZEOF_INT128__`. If the macro is defined and the value is 16 or more then 128-bit types are available. Also see [128-bit integer - nonsensical documentation?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00176.html) on the GCC mailing list.

Comment: Exactly because it is emulated, I though that it should be available on 32-bit platforms as well.

Comment: it will be available on ARM64, MIPS64 or x86_64. @Tamas emulated operations are only supported for values that are twice the register width

Comment: @phuclv - Do you recall which NDK first provided 64-bit support?

Comment: I don't use NDK but [the first gcc with `__int128_t` I can confirm is 4.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5576526/995714#comment90833163_5576526)

Comment: 64 bit support was introduced for android-21, Lollipop, which was released in Nov.2014. Corresponding NDK, r. 10, became official in July that year. I am not sure it had `__int128_t` then.